# Web Scraping with Selenium - Detecting a dropdown menu

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Selenium version 3.141.0

I'm writing a web scraping script that should select a certain option from a dropdown menu with Selenium webdriver. The problem is, I cannot seem to detect this dropdown menu element. I tried detecting it with Class and by CSS selector, but it's still undetectable.

the dropdown menu is a status menu, it contains:

- Draft
- Submitted
- Reviewed
- Released
- Rejected
- Obsolete

This is the HTML code of the part of the page where the dropdown menu is:

```html
<div class="controls col-md-5 angular2-multiselect" id="status-field">
   <ctf-angular2-multiselect class="defaultSettings ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty">
      <div class="cuppa-dropdown" qa-name="dropdown-multiselect">
         <div class="selected-list" tabindex="0">
            <div class="c-btn" qa-name="toggle-dropdown-statusField">
               <!----><!----><!---->
               <span>
                  <!----><span qa-name="item-0">Draft</span>
               </span>
               <!----><!----><!---->
               <div class="dropdown-caret"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="dropdown-container" qa-name="dropdown" hidden="">
            <div class="dropdown-list">
               <div class="list-area" qa-name="list-area">
                  <!----><!----><!----><!----><!---->
                  <ul class="lazyContainer">
                     <!----><!---->
                     <span>
                        <!---->
                        <li class="pure-checkbox single-select-label-selected">
                           <!----><label qa-name="item-0" title="Draft" class="single-select-label">Draft</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="pure-checkbox">
                           <!----><label qa-name="item-1" title="Submitted" class="single-select-label">Submitted</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="pure-checkbox">
                           <!----><label qa-name="item-2" title="Reviewed" class="single-select-label">Reviewed</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="pure-checkbox">
                           <!----><label qa-name="item-3" title="Released" class="single-select-label">Released</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="pure-checkbox">
                           <!----><label qa-name="item-4" title="Rejected" class="single-select-label">Rejected</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="pure-checkbox">
                           <!----><label qa-name="item-5" title="Obsolete" class="single-select-label">Obsolete</label>
                        </li>
                     </span>
                     <!---->
                  </ul>
                  <!----><!----><!----><!---->
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </ctf-angular2-multiselect>
</div>
```

Apparently I'm not that good with HTML, so I was depending on IDs to detect elements in the previous codes I wrote. This code doesn't have any.

This is how the GUI looks like:
[Picture of GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5ztn.png)

I tried using classes to detect the dropdown menu like this:

```
Select(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ctf-angular2-multiselect')).select_by_value("Released")
```

But it doesn't work.
Trying to detect with ID like this:

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_id('status-field')).select_by_value("Released")
```

doesn't work either

Comment: This is not a 'Select' type dropdown, it is an unordered list type, so you cannot use 'Select'.  Use normal actions - click on the dropdown and select the desired option.

Comment: Okay but aside from that, how can we detect the element of the dropdown menu itself?

Comment: Can you post the URL or complete HTML source?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, because the page requires credentials to be able to view it. 
However, I posted the HTML part of the page where the unordered list is.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two challenges to overcome:

1. This isn't a normal html select. You need to click on things through Selenium.
2. The 'dropdown-container' is hidden. You need click on whatever opens it first.

Should we assume the div with the 'c-btn' class opens the drop down? I'd normally check in chrome
dev tools if that element has event listeners **or** use chrome to
save element as a variable and run a js click on it to verify it's
the right element to click before adding it in selenium

[image: save element as global variable]

[image: Attempting a click with JS in chrome]

Once .dropdown-container is not longer hidden. I think your life would be easier with using xpath to select the list elements. to  select the 'Released' option, the xpath would just be `//label[@title='Released']`

You can also use chrome dev tools to verify xpath selections before adding to your selenium script.

[image: verifying xpath in chrome]

With python selenium, you can then click on your xpath selection like this:

```
driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, "//label[@title='Released']").click()
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I made it work with the following: 
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.dropdown-caret').click()` -- to unhide the hidden menu
Then like you said `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@title='Released']").click()`

Comment: Sweet. Glad you were able to solve it!